# How do I write applets for Cinnamon?

Tags: desktop-environments, applet, cinnamon

I'm very excited about the cinnamon desktop environment and want to write applets for it.

How can this be done?

Where can I find information and tutorials about it? (I have searched in google, but was unable to find any examples)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cinnamon applets are written in JavaScript. There are a number of fairly complete tutorials:

- [How To Make A Cinnamon Applet (Force Quit Applet Tutorial)](https://projects.linuxmint.com/reference/git/cinnamon-tutorials/write-applet.html)
- [Hello World Desklet Tutorial](http://www.erikedrosa.com/2014/12/31/hello-world-desklet-tutorial.html)
- [Settings Applet](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031180036/http://cinnamondocumentation.wikinet.org/wiki/Settings_Applet_Tutorial)

Comment: It looks like the only language with tutorials for making applets is Bash; are other languages like C++ not supported?

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: It seems that everything in https://developer.linuxmint.com has been moved to https://projects.linuxmint.com . I fixed the link, it will be visible once the edit has been approved.

Comment: And it seems that i can't edit my own comments... Can someone remove the "I fixed the link, it will be visible once the edit has been approved"-part in my previous comment ? (And also remove this comment)